# WordPress Sort By ID then Date

Tags: wordpress

I have a list of posts on WordPress. I would like 3 specific ones (in any order) to be displayed FIRST, and then the rest after to be **ordered by date**.

Here is the bit of code:

```
order_by="date"
sort_order="DESC"
```

Comment: you could create two queries - one that only gets the specific ones - and one that exclude the specific ones.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved with different ways. Here is one of them:
Getting all IDs ordered by date, then prepend given ID-s to them, then ordering by post__in parameter.

```
global $wpdb;
$post_ids=array();
$sql_results=$wpdb->get_results("select ID from $wpdb->posts where 
                                post_status='publish' and post_type='post'
                                order by date desc");
foreach($sql_results as $sr){
$post_ids[]=$sr->ID;
}

$post_ids_pre=array(123,122,222);//these are the posts which should appear first;
$post_ids_pre=array_merge($post_ids_pre,$post_ids);

$final_posts=get_posts(array("post__in"=>$post_ids_pre,'orderby'=>'post__in'));
```

Comment: sorry for my ignorance, but here is the chunk of code that I have to edit: 


[line_solid icon="circle"][foliof all="TOATE PROIECTELE" num="60" columns="4" gap="0" 

order_by="ID" sort_order="DESC" 

cols="3"]


I'm not sure where to add the code you provided for me. Again (sorry I don't have a lot of experience in coding)